# How do I disable rounded corners for the main view of my entire iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, ios

When running my iPhone app, the app's entire UI has rounded corners (i.e. the area underneath the status bar). The UI is set up using a storyboard, which does not show the rounded corners. How do I turn off the rounded corners? I have tried the following in my `AppDelegate's` `didFinishLoading` method:

```
[self.window.layer setCornerRadius:0.0];
```

but it made no difference. Any ideas?

Comment: I think this couldn't be changed if you have a status bar on top. IOS would let you do this. My solution was to remove the statusbar on top and replace it with my own. Try this! There are a lot of sample codes for status bars. This would actually solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this code.

```
self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
```

It may remove corner radius.

Answer (score 0):

This is something that is part of iOS itself. One way around it would be to create a full screen application and do it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a Base View Controller with corners of your choice and inherit the remaining view controllers from the base. I think this might work.

Answer (score 0):

Programmatically, in the main view controller, on viewWillLoad(), maybe do something like:

```
viewController.view.layer.cornerRadius = 0;
```

Might work...hope so.